# Gradle Multiproject jar doesnt include dependent classes

Tags: maven, jar, gradle, dependencies

This might be a silly question to ask but i m having some serious issues understanding gradle compile

-Lets say i have i have project structure like this

```
proj-- pro1--src
           --build.gradle
    -- pro2--src
       --build.gradle
    --build.gradle
    --settings.gradle
```

and pro2 has 2 dependencies say log4j and pro1

now when i try to run gradle jar task it generates a build directory containing the jar "pro2.jar"
but it doesn't include the dependent classes of pro1

but in maven this works fine

please help me out

Thanks

Comment: you need to include some code to know what is going on here. build.gradle dependency definitions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for above.
Turns out i was wrong. It did the same thing in maven also.

To include all the dependecies in maven an additional plugin is used .
"maven-dependency-plugin"

And in case of gradle we need to create a fatJar. Or for more customization we can create a ShadowJar

---

### fatJar

```html
jar{
from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```